# String translation missing

Tags: magento-1.8, localisation, translate

I've translated the string "Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please click here." in app/locale/it_IT Mage_Customer.csv

```
"Account confirmation is required. Please, check your e-mail for confirmation link. To resend confirmation email please <a href=""%s"">click here</a>.","Conferma account richiesto. Per favore, controlla la tua e-mail per il link di conferma.. Per rinviare l\'email di conferma  <a href=""%s"">clicca qui</a>."
```

But I still get it in english...
As far as I see it's the only string that I don't get translated in italian, why is that?

Comment: Have you opened the inline translation to see which helper / file is calling the translation, or if it's bypassed there?

Comment: Don't know what you mean.
Inline translation doesn't work for me. If I enable it and than click on the little books in my site it doesn't do anything, no translation window appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that magento uses two similar lines:

> Account confirmation is required. Please, check your e-mail for confirmation link. To resend confirmation email please click here.

is used in `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::_involveNewCustomer()` and `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::_involveNewCustomer()`

and

> Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please click here.

is used in `Mage_Customer_AccountController::_successProcessRegistration()`

The difference is in *e-mail → email*, *confirmation → the confirmation*

Add one more line to you `app/locale/it_IT Mage_Customer.csv`

```
"Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href=""%s"">click here</a>.","Conferma account richiesto. Per favore, controlla la tua e-mail per il link di conferma.. Per rinviare l'email di conferma  <a href=""%s"">clicca qui</a>."
```

And there is no need to escape quote sign

Comment: I've tried adding that line to Mage_Cusomer.csv in the line next to the e-mail one.
Updated Magento Cache, cleared chrome cache, but nothing changes.

What you mean when you say?
> And there is no need to escape quote sign?

Comment: Make sure you translate the phrase from Mage_Customer_AccountController::_successProcessRegistration. And no need to escape in the l’email

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have well the translation function in the file of the translated word `<?php echo $this->__('your string ...')?>`
2. if you can't translate it, you can simply use the [inline](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) translation,the translation will be stored in database `core_translate` table (the hight priority one).